# Not getting expected PHP cURL response

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I have the following PHP code:

```
<?php
$data = array("client_id" => "sipgate-app-web", "grant_type" => "password", "username" => "my_username", "password" => "my_password");
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init('https://api.sipgate.com/login/sipgate-apps/protocol/openid-connect/token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Accept: application/json'
));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo $result;
?>
```

Unfortunately, I'm not getting the expected response. The response I'm receiving is:

> {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Missing form
>   parameter: grant_type"}

When using an online cURL tool like https://onlinecurl.com with the same data (URL, header, data) as in my cURL PHP code, I'm getting the right response. This means, there's something wrong with my PHP code. I'm not getting any error in the PHP error log.

The manual says I have to use the following cURL code:

```
 curl \
--request POST \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--data-urlencode "client_id=sipgate-app-web" \
--data-urlencode "grant_type=password" \
--data-urlencode "username=my_username" \
--data-urlencode "password=my_password" \
https://api.sipgate.com/login/sipgate-apps/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

Since I'm new to cURL, after googling a lot, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Can anybody help me?

**EDIT:** You can test my PHP code above as it is. You should get the following response, if the code is working:

> {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid user
>   credentials"}

Comment: Maybe get rid of the `Content-Type` form header. You're not wanting to send a form, you're sending JSON.

Comment: Do you sure about `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? Maybe it should be `Content-Type: application/json`?

Comment: @Jonnix This doesn't change anything. I updated my question with the cURL code. Does this give you any hint?

Comment: @marv255 This doesn't change anything. I updated my question with the cURL code. Does this give you any hint?

Comment: Okay, going by your update, if you want it to be the same as your cli curl request, keep the current content-type, stop `json_encode`ing your data and instead just pass it as the value for POSTFIELDS.

Comment: @David do you use [`OAuth 2.0 Server`](https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/)?

Comment: @Jonnix I removed `$data_string = json_encode($data);` and updated `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);` but it's still the same.

Comment: @marv255 I'm not sure, I'm using shared hosting.

Comment: @Jonnix You can test my PHP code as it is. You should get the following response, if the code is working: `{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid user credentials"}`

Comment: For reference, my suggestion of passing $data directly into POSTFIELDS is probably not working because curl will then decide to send the data encoded as `multipart/form-data`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the manual, your request needs to have the `Content-Type` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` which looks like this:

```
key1=value1&key2=value2
```

Thus you need to convert your array into such a string either manually or with `http_build_query`, like so:

```
$data_string = http_build_query( $data );
```

Comment: Wow, you're great, thank you, this is working: `$data_string = "client_id=sipgate-app-web&grant_type=password&username=my_username&password=my_password";` I also had to remove `json_encode()`.

Comment: Yeah, the above is supposed to be instead of `json_encode`. Glad to know it's working!

Answer (score 0):

I am consuming one of the API using following PHP CURL, Give this a try and pass your credentials i.e username and password in "your username" and "your password".

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.sipgate.com/login/sipgate-apps/protocol/openid- 
connect/token",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>"{\r\n\client_id:\"sipgate-app- 
web\",\r\n\tgrant_type\"password\",\r\n\tusername:\"your 
username\",\r\n\tpassword:\"your password\"\r\n}",
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
"Accept: application/json",
"Content-Type: application/json"
),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
echo $response;
} ?>
```

Comment: Is this solution better than @krimaeus answer?